# XPath to select grandparent and specific uncle node

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I am using XPath in R, and have an XML structure like this:

```
library(XML)

xml1 <- xmlParse('
<L0>
    <L1>
        <ID>Get this ID</ID>
        <L1N1>Ignore node 1</L1N1>
        <L1N2>
            <L2>
                <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
            </L2>
        </L1N2>
        <L1N3>Ignore node 3</L1N3>
    </L1>
    <L1>
        <ID>Get this ID</ID>
        <L1N1>Ignore node 1</L1N1>
        <L1N2>
            <L2>
                <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
            </L2>
        </L1N2>
        <L1N4>Ignore node 4</L1N4>
    </L1>
    <L1>
        <ID>Ignore this ID</ID>
        <L1N1>Ignore node 1</L1N1>
        <L1N3>Ignore node 3</L1N3>
        <L1N4>Ignore node 4</L1N4>
    </L1>
</L0>
                 ')
```

I would like to extract each `L2` node and an uncle node (such as `ID`), but not other uncles.  Each extracted result should go back to the grandparent node, `L1`.  Here is the **desired output**:

```
## [[1]]
## <L1>
##   <ID>Get this ID</ID>
##   <L1N2>
##     <L2>
##       <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
##     </L2>
##  </L1N2>
## </L1> 

## [[2]]
## <L1>
##   <ID>Get this ID</ID>
##   <L1N2>
##     <L2>
##       <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
##     </L2>
##   </L1N2>
## </L1>
```

I can get the `L1` nodes containing `L2` descendants:

```
getNodeSet(xml1, "//L1[descendant::L2]")
## [[1]]
## <L1>
##   <ID>Get this ID</ID>
##   <L1N1>Ignore node 1</L1N1> ## *Want to exclude this*
##   <L1N2>
##     <L2>
##       <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
##     </L2>
##   </L1N2>
##   <L1N3>Ignore node 3</L1N3> ## *Want to exclude this*
## </L1> 
## 
## [[2]]
## <L1>
##   <ID>Get this ID</ID>
##   <L1N1>Ignore node 1</L1N1> ## *Want to exclude this*
##   <L1N2>
##     <L2>
##       <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
##     </L2>
##   </L1N2>
##   <L1N4>Ignore node 4</L1N4> ## *Want to exclude this*
## </L1>
```

...but this includes the uncles that I don't want.  I can exclude those uncles and select the child nodes of `L1` that I do want:

```
getNodeSet(xml1, "//L1/*[self::ID | child::L2]")
## [[1]]
## <ID>Get this ID</ID> 
##   
## [[2]]
## <L1N2>
##   <L2>
##     <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
##   </L2>
## </L1N2> 
## 
## [[3]]
## <ID>Get this ID</ID> 
##   
## [[4]]
## <L1N2>
##   <L2>
##     <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
##   </L2>
## </L1N2> 
## 
## [[5]]
## <ID>Ignore this ID</ID>
```

...but now `ID` and `L2` are separate rather than under `L1`, and it's also including the elements from the third `L1` node that doesn't have an `L2`.

Can XPath return the desired results?  If not, can I use something else in R to achieve the results?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want (using your `xml1`):

```
trim <- function(node) {
  names     <- names(node)
  to.remove <- names[!(names %in% c("ID","L1N2"))]
  removeChildren(node,kids=to.remove)
}
lapply(xml1["//L1[descendant::L2]"],trim)
#  [[1]]
# <L1>
#   <ID>Get this ID</ID>
#   <L1N2>
#     <L2>
#       <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
#     </L2>
#   </L1N2>
# </L1> 
# 
# [[2]]
# <L1>
#   <ID>Get this ID</ID>
#   <L1N2>
#     <L2>
#       <L2N1>Get this node and all others in L2</L2N1>
#     </L2>
#   </L1N2>
# </L1>
```

Of course you could use an anonymous function and put this on one line:

```
lapply(xml1["//L1[descendant::L2]"],function(node) removeChildren(node,kids=names(node)[!(names(node)%in%c("ID","L1N2"))]))
```